# How do I stop a file being imported more than once with SASS and Midscape?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sass, mindscape

I am just learning Sass and have used the @import. I have the following situation...

> _master.scss   <--  this contains all my global variables like color
>
> _child1.scss   <-- this is for one of my child pages but it needs stuff from master
>
> _child2.scss   <-- this is for one of other my child pages but it also needs stuff from master

Now the problem is _master is getting quite big. So when I save my Scss files (the children) using Mindscape tools in Visual Studio 2012 I notice that the generated css files include ALL the css from the master file for both children.

Essentially I am getting duplicate css every time I want to reference the  master file with '@import' which is not good for performance. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding, it sounds like you could really benefit from better use of [partials](http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html#id1). If You don't want *all* of _master.scss to be imported, you should break it apart into components and then import those as you need them.

For example, if `master.scss` contains all the fonts on your site, the colors, and the column layout, you could break it down to something like the following:

```
_fonts.scss
_colors.scss
_column.scss
```

In `master.scss`, you'd import each. Then you could import these smaller files into `child1` and `child2` as you need them.

If this isn't what you're looking for, please try clarifying your question and I might be able to help a bit more.

UPDATE: After discussing with Imjared he said that I should just create a file with variables in only. This would seem to work for me so I am updating this answer and marking it as correct.

Comment: Yeah this is what I have done. So if I do as you have said and I want to use a variable for $black. And that variable is in _fonts.scss AND it is in _colours.scss AND it is is Child 1. then I still have to import master into all .scss sheets don't i?

Comment: Why not just have _variables.scss and import *that*? Imports aren't necessarily a bad thing if they're just importing non-compiled content.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this duplicate SCSS using this snippet to import content:

```
// src/main/scss/import-once-workaround.scss
$imported-once-files: () !default;

@function not-imported($name) {
  $imported-once-files: $imported-once-files !global;
  $module_index: index($imported-once-files, $name);
  @if (($module_index == null) or ($module_index == false)) {
    $imported-once-files: append($imported-once-files, $name);
    @return true;
  }
  @return false;
}
```

Importing files are done then by:

```
@if not-imported("font") { @import "font"; }
```

I used this approach instead of Zurb's to get StyleDocco work, see http://paul.wellnerbou.de/2015/05/18/avoid-multiple-imports-of-the-same-scss-file-with-sass/